# SQL syntax error for update or alter table root user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, unix

after new installation of `ubuntu 20.04` i get error to connect to mysql with `root` user. for below commands after using

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
mysql -u root
```

i get syntax error and i can't update root password:

Mysql version:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

command:

```
update `user` set `authentication_string`=PASSWORD("") where `User`='root';
    >ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("") where `User`='root'' at line 1
```

and when i try to use `Alter` command i get this message:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
    >ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error you got on the first statement was because MySQL 8.0 doesn't recognize PASSWORD as a built-in function anymore.

The `PASSWORD()` function was deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and removed in MySQL 8.0. See documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

The proper way to reset the root password in MySQL 8.0 is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

You restart mysqld with `skip-grant-tables` as you have done. Then open the MySQL client as you have done, without giving a password.

Then reload the grant tables so account-management statements work. I think this is the step you're missing.

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then you can do the ALTER USER statement:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use single quote, not double 
or set password don't use empty string

```
update user set `authentication_string`=PASSWORD('') where user='root';
```

or

```
update user set `authentication_string`=PASSWORD('yourpassword') where user='root';
```

then flush!

```
flush privileges;
```